# Spring store data cache vs session

Tags: spring, web-services, caching, schedule

I need to recover information from an openData through a web service and then display it in a web application developed in Spring Boot. What I want to do is to recover that information once and update it periodically (every 3 hours).

The question I have is that I would like to know what is the best way to implement this as I consider two possibilities:

1. Create a bean and store the data in session

   @Component
   @Scope("session")
   public class Foo { .. }
2. Store the information in cache

   @Cacheable ("foo")

What do you think is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the info per user?  If it's not then you have to put in the cache. And if it is per user you have to put it in the session!